# Spark structured streaming query always starts with auto.offset.rest=earliest even though auto.offset.reset=latest is set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I have a weird issue with trying to read data from Kafka using Spark structured streaming.
My use case is to be able to read from a topic from the largest/latest offset available.

My read configs:

```
val data = spark
     .readStream
     .format("kafka")
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "some xyz server")
     .option("subscribe", "sampletopic")
     .option("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
     .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
     .option("kafkaConsumer.pollTimeoutMs", 20000)
     .option("failOnDataLoss","false")
     .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger",20000)
     .load()
```

My write configs:

```
data
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .queryName("test") 
    .format("parquet")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "s3://somecheckpointdir")
    .start("s3://outpath").awaitTermination()
```

Versions used:

- `spark-core_2.11 : 2.2.1`
- `spark-sql_2.11 : 2.2.1`
- `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11 : 2.2.1`

I have done my research online and from [the Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/documentation.html0/

I am using the new consumer apis and as the documentation suggests i just need to set auto.offset.reset to "latest" or startingOffsets to "latest"  to ensure that my Spark job starts consuming from the the latest offset available per partition in Kafka.

I am also aware that the setting `auto.offset.reset` only kicks in when a new query is started for the first time and not on a restart of an application in which case it will continue to read from the last saved offset.

I am using s3 for checkpointing my offsets. and I see them being generated under s3://somecheckpointdir.

The issue I am facing is that the Spark job always read from earliest offset even though latest option is specified in the code during startup of application when it is started for the first time and I see this in the Spark logs.
`auto.offset.reset = earliest` being used. I have not seen posts related to this particular issue.

I would like to know if I am missing something here and if someone has seen this behavior before. Any help/direction will indeed be useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

1. All Kafka configurations should be set with `kafka.` prefix. Hence the correct option key is `kafka.auto.offset.reset`.
2. You should never set `auto.offset.reset`. Instead, "set the source option `startingOffsets` to specify where to start instead. Structured Streaming manages which offsets are consumed internally, rather than rely on the kafka Consumer to do it. This will ensure that no data is missed when new topics/partitions are dynamically subscribed. Note that `startingOffsets` only applies when a new streaming query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off." [1]

[1] http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zsxwing. I have followed what you mentioned and did not set auto.offset.reset. Instead set startingOffsets to latest. But i still see "auto.offset.reset = earliest "in the logs and latest setting hasn't taken affect.

Comment: There is nothing Spark can do since the log is outputted by Kafka.

Comment: Hi, how do you prevent reading the same data? What I mean is that if I set startingOffsets to earliest and than my code crashes / I stops it, when I re-run the code, it will read all the messages again from kafka. How can I read only unread messages and recover lost data with checkpointing? @zsxwing

Comment: earliest or latest is resolved to a real offset when you start a query. After that, Spark will track the progress and save it in the checkpoint. When a query is restarted, Spark will read the offset value from the checkpoint.

Comment: @zsxwing  whta do you mean by restarted? graceful termination and then re-run? Or after a crash? thx

Comment: It doesn't matter. As long as you provide the same checkpoint location, Spark will pick up the last failed offset from the checkpoint.

Comment: 'You should never set auto.offset.reset ' This statement doesn't make sense. FYI  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19680 , https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3370

Comment: @RonF since Spark Structured Streaming relies on checkpoint dir for offset tracking, try updating checkpoint dir to a new (empty) location. This will treat the query as *new* and will read from `latest`

Answer (score 2):

Update:
So i have done some testing on a local kafka instance with a controlled set of messages going in to kafka. I see that expected behavior is working fine when property startingOffsets is set to earlier or latest.

But the logs always show the property being pickup as earliest, which is a little misleading. 
auto.offset.reset=earliest, even though i am not setting it.

Thank you.

Comment: I have tested this on my side as well, so if you are setting the `startingOffsets` to `latest` it actually reads from the latest offsets in the partition but in the log it will still show `auto.offset.reset = earliest` which is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set auto.offset.reset in Spark Streaming as per the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html). For setting to latest you just need to set the source option `startingOffsets` to specify where to start instead (earliest or latest). Structured Streaming manages which offsets are consumed internally, rather than rely on the kafka Consumer to do it. This will ensure that no data is missed when new topics/partitions are dynamically subscribed.

It clearly says that following fields can't be set and the Kafka source or sink will throw an exception:

1. group.id
2. auto.offset.reset
3. key.deserializer
4. value.deserializer
5. key.serializer
6. value.serializer
7. enable.auto.commit
8. interceptor.classes

Answer (score 0):

For Structured Streaming can set `startingOffsets` to `earliest` so that every time you consume from the earliest available offset. The following will do the trick

```
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
```

---

However note that this is effective just for newly created queries:

[`startingOffsets`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

> The start point when a query is started, either `"earliest"` which is
>   from the earliest offsets, `"latest"` which is just from the latest
>   offsets, or a json string specifying a starting offset for each
>   TopicPartition. In the json, `-2` as an offset can be used to refer to
>   earliest, `-1` to latest. Note: For batch queries, latest (either
>   implicitly or by using `-1` in json) is not allowed. **For streaming
>   queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that
>   resuming will always pick up from where the query left off**. Newly
>   discovered partitions during a query will start at earliest.

---

Alternatively, you might also choose to change the consumer group every time:

```
.option("kafka.group.id", "newGroupID")
```

Comment: Setting Group ID wont work and should not be set in Spark Structured Streaming as already pointed out above. Also the question was about setting the configuration for reading the message from the latest partition not from the earliest. I may be missing something but not sure how this will help.